# How do I get the section index for a row index in objective-c and UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4

I want to select a given row in the UTTableView from a index but need to know also the section index.

```
 int localCurrentIndexPath = 9;

 NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:localCurrentIndexPath inSection:??];
```

I need fill in the inSection part.  Do I need to supply the inSection value?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you only have 1 section, then use 0.